# Foreign Key in RazorSQL (SyBase) with sp_fkeys

Tags: foreign-keys, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa, razorsql

Trying to discover Foreign Keys of a table using RazorSQL, but when i use this command:
`EXEC SP_FKEYS <table_name>`
the information is always empty.

Obs: The paste of the columns table that have foreign key columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from SYSFOREIGNKEYS where primary_tname='table_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I'm assuming you're using the (Sybase) ASE product ...

If by 'foreign key' you're referring to referential integrity (RI) *foreign key* constraints, try:

```
exec sp_helpconstraint <table_name>
```

`sp_helpconstraint` will display all *primary*, *unique*, *foreign key* and *check* constraints on a table. [These constraints are created via the `create table`/`alter table` commands.]

---

The `sp_fkeys`/`sp_pkeys` procs are a throwback to earlier times when:

- ASE did not have table-level RI constraints so ...
- triggers had to be used to enforce RI requirements and therefore ...
- `sp_fkeys`/`sp_pkeys` were used to 'document' these trigger-based RI
  constraints so that 3rd party apps had a means of querying the
  database for RI constraint details

The accuracy of the results from running `sp_fkeys`/`sp_keys` is dependent on whether or not the dbo/table owner remembers to 'document' these RI constraints.

There is no relationship between actual/enforced RI constraints (created via the `create table`/`alter table` commands) and 'documented' RI constraints (created via `sp_fkeys`/`sp_pkeys` invocations).

Comment: i tried your solution, but is gives me and error: ERROR[SyBase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Anywhere] Transact-SQL feature not supported Error Code : -611.

Comment: According to the error message you're using the (Sybase) SQLAnywhere (aka Adaptive Server Anywhere) RDMBS product ... that's different from the ASE product (my assumption). I've edited your question's tags ... this may help flag down someone with SQLAnywhere experience that can answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to search another solutions with those new informations